# miles per gallon gui program python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an assignment that I am having troubles with. The code works but the problem I am having now is getting it to round, I cant seem to find the right place to be placing the ".2f". As well as showing errors for not using numericals or negative numbers. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
import tkinter

class MPG:
    def __init__(self):
        # create main window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        # create four frames
        self.gallons_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.miles_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.mpg_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)


        self.gallons_label = tkinter.Label(self.gallons_frame, \
                                       text='Enter the number of gallons: ')
        self.gallons_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.gallons_frame, \
                                       width=10)
        self.gallons_label.pack(side='left')
        self.gallons_entry.pack(side='left')


        self.miles_label = tkinter.Label(self.miles_frame, \
                                           text='Enter the number of miles: ')
        self.miles_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.miles_frame, \
                                           width=10)
        self.miles_label.pack(side='left')
        self.miles_entry.pack(side='left')


        self.result_label = tkinter.Label(self.mpg_frame, \
                                       text='Miles Per Gallon')
        self.mpg = tkinter.StringVar() 
        self.mpg_label = tkinter.Label(self.mpg_frame, \
                                       textvariable=self.mpg)
        self.result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.mpg_label.pack(side='left')


        self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, \
                                          text='Calculate MPG', \
                                          command=self.calc_mpg)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, \
                                          text='Quit', \
                                          command=self.main_window.destroy)
        self.calc_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')


        self.gallons_frame.pack()
        self.miles_frame.pack()
        self.mpg_frame.pack()
        self.button_frame.pack()

    # the calc_mpg is the callback function for the calc_button
    def calc_mpg(self):
        # Get miles and gallons and store them in variables
        self.gallons = float(self.gallons_entry.get())
        self.miles = float(self.miles_entry.get())

        # calculate the MPG
        self.miles_per_gallon = self.miles / self.gallons

        # update the mpg_label
        self.mpg.set(str(round(self.miles_per_gallon)))

carmpg = MPG()
```

Comment: Quick unrelated tip: in Python, you don't need a `\` to continue an arguments list onto another line.

Comment: You can set the numeric value with `self.mpg.set('%.2f' % round(self.miles_per_gallon, 2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the built in function [round](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round). Also, I think you may be missing an int to string call.

```
# the calc_mpg is the callback function for the calc_button
def calc_mpg(self):
    # Get miles and gallons and store them in variables
    self.gallons = float(self.gallons_entry.get())
    self.miles = float(self.miles_entry.get())

    # calculate the MPG
    self.miles_per_gallon = self.miles / self.gallons

    # update the mpg_label
    self.mpg.set(str(round(self.miles_per_gallon, 2)))
```

Comment: that rounds as a whole I need 2 decimal places.

Comment: got it, just add a 2 as a second argument to round.